# Maven: test dependencies

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

**Problem:** Maven can't find some dependencies inside my tests

```
import org.hamcrest.core.StringStartsWith; // HIGHLIGHTED AS RED IN INTELLIJ
```

It's imported like this in my pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I already tried:

1. mvn test-compile
2. Invalidate Intellij caches
3. Restart Intellij
4. Clear .m2 and rebuild project

Comment: Are you sure you're importing this class in a class in your tests and not in your main code, right?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yes, because it doesn't work only on my PC! ((

Comment: In such cases for me helps reimporting project (create as new maven project)

Comment: @Natalia step-by-step please

Comment: @V_B I mean : Project -> Import Project. As it works when you run from command line, than it is problem in idea.

Comment: @SparkOn that's work! Still Have no idea why it works for other people with hamcrest-core

Answer (score 2):

The way to figure this out is to run your tests from the command line, via `mvn verify`, and ensure that things compile and run correctly. This will allow you to determine whether the problem is in your POM configuration, or something unique to Intellij.

If it's a problem in Intellij, it is very likely to be something around folder configuration: generally only folders marked as "Test Source Root" will have access to things in the test scope.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the dependency is at least specified under `<project><dependencies>` on not only under `<project><dependencyManagement><dependencies>`.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to (re)load Maven dependencies. From the [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/delegate-build-and-run-actions-to-maven.html#maven_reimport):
" Every time you manually change the pom.xml file in the editor, you need to load the changes. IntelliJ IDEA displays a notification icon in the right part of the editor suggesting to Load Maven Changes made to the project (⌘⇧I)."
(Note this is the macOs shortcut, as I use macOS)

Alternatively / in addition you might want to se auto-reload.
Find how to in the [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/delegate-build-and-run-actions-to-maven.html#auto_reload_maven).